# PayPal cannot pay without login

Tags: php, html, paypal

I am developing a website with PayPal integration for people to pay money. At my PayPal payment page there contain form for buyers to make payment without PayPal account. During the sandbox development, everything works fine. Now, I am using real account. The problem is, now buyers can't pay without login. When try to pay with the form, PayPal return error saying:

`You cannot use an e-mail address or card number that belongs to an existing PayPal account. If you have a PayPal account, please log in. If you don't, please change the e-mail address or card number and try again.`

The thing is, I have tried it with card number and email that has never been used with PayPal, but I am also getting the same error message.

Do you have any idea why it happen? How can I solve it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its the cookie issue, Check out [this link](https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/About-Payments-Archive/You-cannot-use-an-e-mail-address-or-card-number-that-belongs-to/td-p/514114)